# Каким образом реализовать запись на консультацию

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Такая задача: Нужно реализовать онлайн запись на прием к специалисту. И все бы ничего, но при записи нужно чтоб пользователь мог выбрать день(то есть дату), и время. 
Не знаю каким образом это лучше реализовать. 
Сделать возможность чтоб пользователь мог сам прописать дату и время - не подходит. Так как записаться можно только на дни с понедельника по пятницу(включительно), и нельзя чтоб несколько пользователей записывались на одно и то же время.

Каким образом реализовать подобное? Буду благодарен за предложения.

Comment: С чем конкретно нужна помощь? С поиском плагинов для отображения календаря на клиентской стороне? или проверки на стороне сервера? Нужно задавать более конкретный вопрос.

Comment: Очевидно, нужно взять какой-то готовый виджет выбора даты (datepicker), отметить неприемные дни, добавить валидацию выбора даты.

Comment: Ну можно сделать, как в большинстве других проектов реализовано. Список дат/календарь. При выборе даты открывается список времени свободного. Либо список времени где как-то выделено свободное, чтобы клиент мог отметить время. Разбить на временные отрезки не проблема, прием то по времени обычно фиксированный. В чем конкретно проблема то состоит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте таблицу записей к доктору, в которой будет время и дата, и естественно номер специалиста. Временные интервалы или произвольное время - это ваше решение, далее выгружаете все через AJAX (хотя можно и без него) на страницу календаря, перебираете все существующие записи к доктору и резервируете временной интервал (x-n,x+n), где n предполагаемое время приема, обычно стандартно это 7-15 минут (можно также использовать время приема для каждой записи, если оно будет отличаться от стандартной консультации) Естественно календарь на выходные дни не выводите, и на backend делаете запрет записи на выходные дни.

В базе данных или в key-value хранилище (memcached, redis) используете блокировки, чтобы 2 пользователя не смогло записаться на одинаковый интервал времени, в фиксированных интервалах это можно реализовать с помощью уникального ключа в БД, в произвольных интервалах придется проверять, есть ли в указанном диапозоне timestamp еще подобная запись.